# Rails: Unable to destroy association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, Users and Conversations are tied through a has_many :through relationship, the association table being conversation_users.

How do I delete an association (a User leaves the Conversation) from the Conversations controller? I tried:

```
def destroy_assoc 
    Conversation.find(params[:id]).conversation_users.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).destroy
    redirect_to :back
end
```

But I got a `undefined method 'eq' for nil:NilClass` error. Here is the log when I call that action:

```
Processing by ConversationsController#destroy_assoc as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"8AT1wx5MUVz1Gsqpp+u+z0vk8uj4F0mAWz5wpn+CjCU=", "username"=>"albert", "id"=>"14"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 8 LIMIT 1
  Conversation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "conversations".* FROM "conversations" WHERE "conversations"."id" = 14 LIMIT 1
  ConversationUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "conversation_users".* FROM "conversation_users" WHERE "conversation_users"."user_id" = 8 AND ("conversation_users".conversation_id = 14) LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 109ms

NoMethodError (undefined method 'eq' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:34:in `destroy_assoc'

Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (7.1ms)
Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (12.9ms)
```

The record is found, but destroy raises an error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Full stack trace:

```
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:83:in `destroy'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:110:in `destroy'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:256:in `destroy'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run_destroy_callbacks'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:256:in `destroy'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:235:in `destroy'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:292:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:139:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:207:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:290:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:235:in `destroy'
app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:34:in `destroy_assoc'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `_run__2060746170__process_action__2040097307__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:82:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `start'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:30
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:27
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

Comment: Your error might be further down in the destroy_assoc method. Include the rest of the method (...) and indicate which is line 34. Also post your rails version.

Comment: I updated my post. Line 34 corresponds to the destroy call. I'm using rails 3.0.9

Comment: The stack trace you are seeing is not complete.

The presence of a 'eq' method leads me thinking there is more, down into the models.

Comment: What kain means is the rest of the stack trace - there should be plenty more after the first line with other files and line numbers, at least if you're running in debug mode.

Comment: Apparently Rails started hiding full stack traces in the logs, but keep them in the usual error pages in development mode. If you are able to get such page (i.e. is not in an AJAX request that you need to inspect) click Full Trace and paste that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the answer to this question:

[undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass with rails 3 and ruby enterprise on ubuntu hardy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124290/undefined-method-eq-for-nilnilclass-with-rails-3-and-ruby-enterprise-on-ubuntu)

If you have no ID field in your association class, it can't be treated as a model, it appears. Are you using a a :has_and_belongs_to_many association with a join table without a primary key `id`?

Comment: absolutely, I had just figured it out and was about to post the answer :) I'm using :has_many, :through but my join table had no primary key, so destroy (and other methods) couldn't work.
I remigrated with a primary key in the join table... and it works!
also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085258/cant-destroy-record-in-many-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
@conversation = current_user.conversation_users.find_by_conversation_id(params[:id])
@conversation.destroy
```

I guess

```
User has_many :conversation_users
User has_many :conversations :through => :conversation_users
```

Does that work? I think it's a cleaner approach at least, letting AR do the job.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I just want to remove the relationship between User and Conversation, not the Conversation.

Comment: sorry, I wrote conversation instead of join_model/association, correcting

Comment: I have edited the answer once again, I should probably stay in bed today as I'm ill ^^